# Is it possible to scan App Clip Code with an Android Phone?

Tags: android, ios, apple-appclips

Apple's App Clip Code is just another type of QR Code. According to https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652661, it seems the App Clip Code can be detected by some type of Android Phones. But when I test with my Mi Phone, nothing happens.

Is there any existing scanner library or any specification on implementing one to detect App Clip Code on Android and iOS apps?

Comment: https://love2dev.com/ios-app-clip/#:~:text=limit%20clip%20size.-,App%20Clip%20Code%20is%20Proprietary,-The%20App%20Clip says, the App Clip Code is proprietary to Apple. I am not sure if it's true.